# How to access date field and display in Liferay Application Display Template (ADT)

Tags: templates, liferay, structure, adt, velocity

I have created a structure that basically serves to collect news article information.  One of the fields is for the date of the article. See image:
[structure for news](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEGCw.png)

I'm selecting this structure from the Asset Publisher, filling out the fields, and saving.  Then I'm trying to view the fields on the page where the asset publisher is. I'm able to access and display all the fields with an Application Display Template (ADT) except for DATE!  I've scoured the Internet for an answer and am turning to the community for help.

This is the code of the Application Display Template that I'm using to select and format the code.

*Disclaimer:  I am not a java programmer, so any additional explanations would be super helpful.

```
<div class="container news-listing">
   <div class="row">
        <div class="span9">

#if (!$entries.isEmpty())

    #foreach ($entry in $entries)

        #set($renderer = $entry.getAssetRenderer() )
        #set($className = $renderer.getClassName() )

        #if( $className == "com.liferay.portlet.journal.model.JournalArticle" )
            #set( $journalArticle = $renderer.getArticle() )
            #set( $document = $saxReaderUtil.read($journalArticle.getContent()) )
            #set( $rootElement = $document.getRootElement() )

            ## FETCH Title
            #set( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='newstitle']") )
            #set( $title = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getStringValue())

            ## FETCH image
            #set( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='featureimage']") )
            #set( $img = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getStringValue())

            ## FETCH FullDescription
            #set( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='newsfulldescription']") )
            #set( $fulldesc = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getStringValue() )

            ## FETCH ShortDescription
            #set( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='newsshortdescription']") )
            #set( $shortdesc = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getStringValue() )

            ## FETCH date
            #set( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='articleDate']") )
            #set( $datetest = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getStringValue() )

            ## FETCH Group
            #set( $xPathSelector = $saxReaderUtil.createXPath("dynamic-element[@name='group']") )
            #set( $Group = $xPathSelector.selectSingleNode($rootElement).getStringValue())

            #set( $link = $assetPublisherHelper.getAssetViewURL($renderRequest, $renderResponse, $entry) ) 
            #if ("$assetLinkBehavior" != "showFullContent") 
                #set( $link = $renderer.getURLViewInContext($renderRequest, $renderResponse, $link) ) 
            #end 

       ##$entry.getExpandoBridge().getAttributeNames()
       $entry.date.getClass().getName()

              <div class="listing">

                        <img src="$img" alt="$img" class="thumbnail">

                        <div class="news-info">

                            <div class="news-date">
                                 <span>$datetest</span> <br/>
                            </div>

                            <p class="news-category">Announcement</p>
                            <h2>$title</h2>
                            <p>$shortdesc</br><a href="$link">Read More  »</a></p>
                        </div>
                </div> 

        #end
    #end

#end
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The template editor (at least in Liferay 7) allows you to add fields by just clicking them. Here's what this one adds to the template:

Freemarker:

```
<#assign articleDate_Data = getterUtil.getString(articleDate.getData())>

<#if validator.isNotNull(articleDate_Data)>
    <#assign articleDate_DateObj = dateUtil.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd", articleDate_Data, locale)>

    ${dateUtil.getDate(articleDate_DateObj, "dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss", locale)}
</#if>
```

or Velocity

```
#set ($articleDate_Data = $getterUtil.getString($articleDate.getData()))

#if ($validator.isNotNull($articleDate_Data))
    #set ($articleDate_DateObj = $dateUtil.parseDate("yyyy-MM-dd",$articleDate_Data, $locale))

    $dateUtil.getDate($articleDate_DateObj, "dd MMM yyyy - HH:mm:ss", $locale)
#end
```

Comment: Just tried this. I'm in 6.2 (sorry if I didn't mention).  I didn't produce the date data.  Not sure what the issue is.